# Why micro soft provide "Current User\Personal\Certificates" and "Local Computer\Personal\Certificates" certificates?

Tags: authentication, certificate, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, ssl-client-authentication

1) Why micro soft provide "Current User\Personal\Certificates" and "Local Computer\Personal\Certificates" certificates? 
2) In case of personal client authentication from which path we should get the certificates
3) Is there any scenario where "Local Computer\Personal\Certificates" certificates" will be used?

I have doubt with both locations of certificate. Which should be take for client authentication.

Answer (score 0):

1) They have different purposes.  CurrentUser is for things that belong to you, a user.  LocalMachine is for things that belong to the machine.  This makes more sense in servers or multi-user workstations.

2) CurrentUser, if it's about the user.

3) Sure.  That's where IIS looks for TLS/SSL certificates, it's where the machine's Remote Desktop identity certificate lives, etc.  Anything which would be related to the name of the computer, or anything that's used by multiple users.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciated your support.